# How to create user level themes like Orkut?

Tags: asp.net

Hai ,

I am doing a community website. Assume that I am giving an option to all my users to choose a theme. That we happen see on websites like Orkut , Gmail etc..Actually we can keep only one theme inside the web config right ?. During dynamic change all the other user's themes will also change. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is user profile.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx

You could find many more samples online